# using document.cookie to delete cookies not working on firefox

Tags: javascript, cookies

below is a simple logout script which is triggered by clicking the "LOGOUT" anchor in the navigation bar in my website.
the code works fine in chrome but doesn't do a thing in firefox.

```
            $('a#UserLogout').on('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault;
                document.cookie = '_session_login=""; expires="Thu, 01-Jan-70 00:00:01 GMT";';
                location.reload();
            });
```

PS. I have another cookie for language preference and it is working code below:

```
function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays)
{
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime()+(exdays*24*60*60));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
    location.reload();
}
```

and i tried using `-365` in the exdays but didn't work as well

Comment: you set your cookie to `""` value... remove all `"`

Comment: I added the quotes in another test i already tried without it.. the script works in chrome though

Comment: How is the cookie being set?

Comment: ended up using ajax to call a php script `setcookie`, this solved the problem

Comment: `.toGMTstring()` is deprecated and should never be used.

Comment: @kehrk, just `.toUTCString` using need instead, but that unrelated to this thread at all.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this issue (FF 29) and solution was to also set path when setting up the cookie. It should not be needed because by specification (and also according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie)) when path is omitted it should default to current path, however it is probably defaulting to / (root) or something else.
Anyway in my case I was deleting the cookie in domain subfolder (for example `www.example.com/SubFolder/`) and specifying matching path (eg. `SubFolder`) allowed me to delete the cookie.
Generally setting the cookie path to location.pathname should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the extra quotes and change it to this

```
document.cookie = '_session_login=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
```

Also you should tell the browser to force the page to load from the server, not the cache

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

Comment: Is the cookie still there? Are you sure it is not the reload pulling the cached page. AKA change `location.reload();` to `location.reload(true);`

Comment: Other option is  `document.cookie = '_session_login=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;; domain=; path=;' If that does not work, than you have some other issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `1970`

```
document.cookie = '_session_login=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
```